# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Wr)[hm -> t]:

Tags: angular, typescript

after installing ngx-spinner and implementing it:
everything was working fine in development environment ,but after running "ng build --prod"
it gave this unknown error:

```
main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Wr)[hm -> t]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[hm -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Wr)[hm -> t]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[hm -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
    at St.get (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1
    at t (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at Mn.get (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1
    at t (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at Mn.get (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at ml (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at zl.get (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at ni (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at v (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
    at v (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
    at polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1
    at a.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main-es2015.c9e9960412d335bdc448.js:1)
    at a.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
    at s.runTask (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
    at _ (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
    at c.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
    at u (polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js:1)
```

what should i do?
my app.module.ts file is :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponentComponent } from './header-component/header-component.component';
import { FooterComponentComponent } from './footer-component/footer-component.component';
import { StoryComponentComponent } from './story-component/story-component.component';
import { HomeComponentComponent } from './home-component/home-component.component';
import { BudgetCodeComponentComponent } from './budget-code-component/budget-code-component.component';
import { ActivityComponentComponent } from './activity-component/activity-component.component';
import { TransferComponentComponent } from './transfer-component/transfer-component.component';
import { LoginModalComponentComponent } from './login-modal-component/login-modal-component.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponentComponent } from './page-not-found-component/page-not-found-component.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { PreviewPostModalComponentComponent } from './preview-post-modal-component/preview-post-modal-component.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { CardComponentComponent } from './card-component/card-component.component';
import { ContactModalComponentComponent } from './contact-modal-component/contact-modal-component.component';
import {Config} from "./classes/config";
import { EditProfileComponentComponent } from './edit-profile-component/edit-profile-component.component';
import { ChangePasswordComponentComponent } from './change-password-component/change-password-component.component';
import { CompanyHomeComponentComponent } from './company-home-component/company-home-component.component';
import {InfiniteScrollModule} from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { LoginComponentComponent } from './login-component/login-component.component';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponentComponent,
    FooterComponentComponent,
    StoryComponentComponent,
    HomeComponentComponent,
    BudgetCodeComponentComponent,
    ActivityComponentComponent,
    TransferComponentComponent,
    LoginModalComponentComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponentComponent,
    PreviewPostModalComponentComponent,
    CardComponentComponent,
    ContactModalComponentComponent,
    EditProfileComponentComponent,
    ChangePasswordComponentComponent,
    CompanyHomeComponentComponent,
    LoginComponentComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [Config],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

where is the problem? everything was working fine locally.
and the problem disappeared when i remove it from the code.
this is the link to the library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner
anyone can help?
i did exactly what mentioned in the documentation

Comment: Hi, What is your angular version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that i had conflicts in versions 
i updated the angular/cli and fixed it